# Continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, $\frac{1}{2} \leq f(x) \leq 1$ and $f(1)=1$. Must there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) \geq x^n$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: I think any differentiable function whose derivative tends to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow1^-$ would provide a counterexample.

Comment: $1-\sqrt{1-x}$ should already do the trick - not so nasty ^^

Comment: @AlexR, your function it isn't greater than 1/2 for every x in [0,1]. =/

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro Oh, my bad. Scaling it will work, though:
$$1- \frac12 \sqrt{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, well actually I started writing this answer before AlexR mentioned this in a comment, but I had to fiddle around with the actual counterexample a lot. So here’s an expansion of the idea AlexR has given:

---

No. Check out $√x$. Now check out $f \colon [0..1] → ℝ,\;  1/2 + \frac{1 - \sqrt[4]{(1-x)}}{2})$. So the “$1/2$” and “$1-x$” stuff is only to fit your requirements and taking $\sqrt[4]{•}$ instead of $\sqrt{•}$ will make it easier soon.

Obviously $f([0..1]) ⊂ [1/2..1]$ and $f(1) = 1$.

Now let $n ∈ ℕ$, $n > 1$ and $x = 1 - 1/n^4 ∈ [0..1]$. Then $f(x) = 1/2 + \tfrac{n-1}{2n} = \tfrac{2n-1}{2n}$.

But, by Bernoulli,
$$x^n = (1 - 1/n^4)^n > 1 - 1/n^3 = \frac{2n - 2/n^2}{2n} > \frac{2n - 1}{2n} = f(x).$$

For $n = 1$, you can take the counterexample for $n = 2$ as then $f(x) < x^2 ≤ x$.

I hope I didn’t make any mistakes.